# Api call is failing using angular/common/http in ionic apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

We are using `HTTPClient` from `angular/common/http` in `ionic` and able to call API's in visual studio code without any issue, However API's are not getting called through apk.

`Error: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED`

As suggested by many forums, We have used flag `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `network_security_config.xml` and `manifest.xml`.

We have also upgraded `gradle` and making apk from both android studio and Visual studio code.

Any pointers will help.

Answer (score 1):

in my config.xml add:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Your Manifest:

```
 <application        
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

My network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
     <domain includeSubdomains="true">your IP here</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ! this did not work. network_security_config.xml is :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain >localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Comment: It did not work, I used IP address with port it gave same error and with IP only it gave me timeout error.

Comment: vesion  cordova? you can using 8.1.1

Comment: We are using cordova version 9.0.0 , ionic CLI: 5.4.1 , Ionic framework : 4.9.1 , Android : 8.1.0

Comment: Please suggest if I shall share menifest/network_security_config/config.xml

Comment: test using cordova 8.1.1